# How can I Dynamically create a UI for the iPhone using Monodevelop

Tags: c#, iphone, xml, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I already have the code I need to get button labels/number of buttons off of an XML file.  Now I need to dynamically generate the UI based on the values I get.  What is the best way to do this?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like any other .NET language, you can easily create any UI programmatically.

I would suggest to read some tutorials from the web such as:

> http://codejim.blogspot.com/2011/03/monotouch-programmatic-ui-design.html

but I would strongly considerate to give Miguel's Dialog library a go as well

> https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog